# If string = string then get the value

Tags: excel

If i have a column and row like so

```
strings   numbers     check     Total
abc         23         abc
abc         12         abb
abb          9         aba
aba          9
aba         12
```

I need to get the total with a forumla
So total for abc would be 23 + 12 
abb would be 9
and aba would be 9+12

how would i get this with a forumla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"=abc",B:B)
```

A more better generalized approach would be:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,D2,B:B)
```

Where `A` is your `strings` column, `B` is your `numbers` column and `D` is your `check` column. And you are inserting this formula on second row because first row is headers, you can drag it down from there and it will update the references.

The result will look like this:

```
strings numbers check   Total
abc         23  abc     35
abc         12  abb     9
abb         9   aba     21
aba         9           0
aba         12          0
```

Use this in any cell but not in column `A`,`B` or `D` because that would give circular referencing error.

Comment: this works if i put the text there but instead of text i need it to look at the cell   something like `=sumif(A:A,"="D4,B:B)`  where D4 = 'abc'

Comment: check my updated answers you can do this by `=SUMIF(A:A,D2,B:B)`, you dont need to specify `=` specifically if you are just mentioning a cell it automatically deducts that you want the value equal to this.

Comment: Ah sweet this works.. ill accept this as answer, but i do have one more small issue..  when i try to select a range it gives me errors..for example i have stings in A C E  and numbers in B D F  . But it will not work if i try to select ACE:ACE instead of just A:A  if you can help thanks if not ill still accept as it answered the question..I did not think a range would make a different when asking

Comment: ok i did it like this SUM(SUMIF(A:A,D4,C:C),SUMIF(B:B,D4,E:E))  ect.. THANK AGAIN

Comment: you cant really reference using `ACE:ACE` format, it is possible when you have continous columns for e.g. to select `A`,`B` and `C` you can use `A:C`. For your case you would need to use nested `SUM(IFs..)`

Answer (score -1):

try using sumif(). you can get more info about it from help in excel

Comment: yea, while i am sure it might beable to doit... i cant figure it out.as i need it to add the value in the row next to the string it finds.